# setting values manually in report viewer when opening rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc

I'm new to rdlc and report viewer object.

I need to create some kind of vaucher which looks like

*-------------------------------------------------------

Voucher is given to ***_*__** (here I place textbox)
From ***_*__*_*__*_*_** (here I place textbox).. and so on

--------------------------------------------------------*

Also I need to be able to print (like pdf for example), with some background image on it.

I'm using VS 2008, Winforms.

I decieded to implement this issue using rdlc and report viewer. But there is one thing I don't understant. 
Is there some way to set values of the textboxes in manual way (without data sources) and just to set TEXT property of all texboxes with actuall values? (like we do in Winforms / Webforms programming).
If not, what is the best way to do that? May be I should use some other tool?

Thanx for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that! Just create some non-queried parameters for the report and set the value of each textbox to:

```
=Parameters!ParameterName.Value
```

...where ParameterName is the actual name of the parameter, as you defined for the report.

Answer (score 1):

You can define parameters for the report (one for each textbox), the textboxes will appear on top of the report, but their content will print fine.